# Python's hasattr on list values of dictionaries always returns false?

Tags: python, list, class, dictionary, hasattr

I have a dictionary that sometimes receives calls for non-existent keys, so I try and use `hasattr` and `getattr` to handle these cases:

```
key_string = 'foo'
print "current info:", info
print hasattr(info, key_string)
print getattr(info, key_string, [])
if hasattr(info, key_string):
    array = getattr(info, key_string, [])
array.append(integer)
info[key_string] = array
print "current info:", info
```

The first time this runs with `integer = 1`:

```
current info: {}
False
[]
current info: {'foo': [1]}
```

Running this code again with `integer = 2`:

```
instance.add_to_info("foo", 2)

current info: {'foo': [1]}
False
[]
current info: {'foo': [2]}
```

The first run is clearly successful (`{'foo': [1]}`), but `hasattr` returns false and `getattr` uses the default blank array the second time around, losing the value of `1` in the process! Why is this?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

`hasattr` does not test for members of a dictionary. Use the `in` operator instead, or the `.has_key` method:

```
>>> example = dict(foo='bar')
>>> 'foo' in example
True
>>> example.has_key('foo')
True
>>> 'baz' in example
False
```

But note that `dict.has_key()` has been deprecated, is recommended against by the PEP 8 style guide and has been removed altogether in Python 3.

Incidentally, you'll run into problems by using a mutable class variable:

```
>>> class example(object):
...     foo = dict()
...
>>> A = example()
>>> B = example()
>>> A.foo['bar'] = 'baz'
>>> B.foo
{'bar': 'baz'}
```

Initialize it in your `__init__` instead:

```
class State(object):
    info = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.info = {}
```

Comment: I'll be damned! I thought I was going crazy. I've always used the `if/in/else` structure for these dictionary testing situations with default values. This time since the actual situation is actually much more intricate than my example, with a few other hasattrs flying around, I favored that "syntax" instead... which obviously doesn't work! I'll remember this gotcha from now on, thanks!

Comment: Also, I'm dealing with info in init appropriately, just wanted to streamline the example.

Answer (score 15):

A dictionary key is not the same as an object attribute

```
thing1 = {'a', 123}
hasattr(thing1, 'a') # False
class c: pass
thing2 = c()
thing2.a = 123
hasattr(thing2, 'a') # True
```

Comment: Ah. This was driving me mad. Thanks for sharing example.

Answer (score 2):

To test for elements in a list/dictionary, use `in`. To use defaults, you can use `dict.get`:

```
def add_to_info(self, key_string, integer):
    array = self.info.get(key_string, [])
    array.append(integer)
    self.info[key_string] = array
```

Or use defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict
class State(object):
    info = defaultdict(list)

    def add_to_info(self, key_string, integer):
        self.info[key_string].append(integer)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you convert your dictionary to a dot dictionary you can use `hasattr` and `getattr` for it:

```
class dotdict(dict):
    """dot.notation access to dictionary attributes"""
    __getattr__ = dict.get
    __setattr__ = dict.__setitem__
    __delattr__ = dict.__delitem__

newdict = dotdict(olddict)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like all you need is one line:

```
def add_to_info(self, key_string, integer):
    self.info.setdefault(key_string, []).append(integer)
```

Answer (score -1):

You may use .get() method on a dict type object. This method doesnt raise a key error if isnt defined. Also, as the getattr() for objects you may specify on it a default value.

```
>> {'name': 'Me'}.get('name1', 'StackOverflow')
>> 'StackOverflow'
```