# Adding property to python dictionary not working according to hasattr

Tags: python

According to https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm I should be able to add a property to a dictionary quite easily, however the hasattr function does not seem to notice any change on the dictionary:

```
obj = {}
obj["foo"] = "bar"
print hasattr(obj, "foo") # prints False
```

Why is this, and is there a workaround?

Comment: do you mean `'print 'foo' in obj`?

Comment: You're adding an item under a key to a dictionary, not a property.

Comment: @IljaEverilä what is the difference, and then how do I add a property?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10724766/pythons-hasattr-on-list-values-of-dictionaries-always-returns-false, for example. And you probably don't want to add properties to dict, really. It is meant for storing values under keys. Do you happen to have a Javascript background? A property is something the object has. On the other hand collections contain items, and a dict is a collection of key, value pairs of sorts. Think Maps in Java.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Haha yeah js and java, I think that's messing me up here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't added a property, you've added a key, which is what dictionaries are for.

The way to tell it a key exists in a dict is to use `in`:

```
print("foo" in bar)
```

Comment: Ok so the items you put in a dictionary aren't really properties?

Comment: No. Python is not JavaScript.