# How to filter an array of objects on nested attribute using lambda and hasattr?

Tags: python, arrays, object, lambda, hasattr

I have the following Python code:

```
myArray = [{ "id": 1, "desc": "foo", "specs": { "width": 1, "height": 1}}, { "id": 2, "desc": "bar", "specs": { "width": 2, "height": 2, "color": "black"}}, { "id": 3, "desc": "foobar"}]
print len(myArray)

myArray_filtered = filter(lambda item : hasattr(item, "specs") and hasattr(item.specs, "color"), myArray)
print len(myArray_filtered)
```

I expect to get length `1` on second print, but it is `0`. Can you tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python's hasattr on list values of dictionaries always returns false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10724766/pythons-hasattr-on-list-values-of-dictionaries-always-returns-false); i.e. use `in` instead.

Comment: If you split your conditions, you'll find your first filter command returns an empty list -- length 0, any further filtering will, similarly return length 0.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I tried to use `myArray_filtered = filter(lambda item : 'specs' in item and 'color' in item.specs), myArray)` but it doesn't work. Sorry this is my first time with Python!

Comment: @hd1 Yes, you are right, I see it now... anyway I can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog your answer has an advantage over mine that if the value of "color" is `None` i would need to use another default

Comment: dictionary items are accessed via [subscription](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=subscription#subscriptions) (e.g., `d['key']`) - they are not [attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=subscription#attribute-references).

Comment: @Chris_Rands your approach would be more succinct for a more deeply nested structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your nested structure, you could use `dict.get` with some default values:

```
>>> myArray_filtered = list(filter(lambda d: d.get("specs", {}).get("color") is not None, myArray))
>>> len(myArray_filtered)
1
>>> myArray_filtered
[{'id': 2, 'desc': 'bar', 'specs': {'width': 2, 'height': 2, 'color': 'black'}}]
```

Comment: @smartmouse You only need the `list()` call in Python 3, but you should really not be learning Python 2 anyway at this stage

Comment: I'm on Python 2.7.x and it works without `list()`. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know how to add more condition? For example if I want to check even `width == 2` ?

Comment: @Chris_Rands Very good solution, I have the same problem that you have solved but instead of the specs being an object it is a list [] How would the same example be with the specs in [] list?

Answer (score 1):

```
myArray_filtered = [v for v in myArray if v.get('specs', {}).get('color')]
print(len(myArray_filtered))
```

Slightly simpler just using list comprehensions.

And you can add to the condition:

```
myArray_filtered = [v for v in myArray if v.get('specs', {}).get('color') and v.get('specs', {}).get('width') == 2]
print(len(myArray_filtered))
```

Comment: In this case how to add more conditions such as `width == 2`?